# What is the proper usage of Bundler groups in Rails 3 applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm finding a disconnect between the description of how Bundler groups are used in Rails and what I see in examples of Bundler groups.

Supposedly, Rails normally loads gems from the default group as well as the group with the same name as the environment.  I commonly see examples, however, that seem to just put things in arbitrarily-named groups, and somehow, they just work.  So what's the real story, or what am I missing?

This example ( http://www.jonathanspies.com/posts/7-Rails-3-and-Shoulda ) for instance, says to list the 'shoulda' gem in a :shoulda group, and says that this works.  The environments that would need this, however, would be "test", and perhaps "development".  What causes gems in the "shoulda" group to be loaded?

In other examples such as http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.programming.tools.cucumber/2691, I see cucumber-rails and related gems being placed into the :test group, but Cucumber tasks run with the "cucumber" environment, so again, how would the gems be loaded when they are needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will see at http://www.jonathanspies.com/posts/7-Rails-3-and-Shoulda they are also saying:

```
In test/test_helper.rb add:
Bundler.require(:shoulda)
```

Which requires the shoulda group.

Comment: Thanks.  That was driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 0):

In my capistrano recipe, Bundler is run with `--without development test` to prevent these groups from being installed which is I guess default behaviour.

Comment: That matches with my understanding that all groups are included during installation unless they are explicitly excluded, but each group must be explicitly required for loading.